# Power light flashing and CMOS checksum bad

Tags: power-supply, cmos

After I press CPU power button the power light is flashing.
After sometimes when I am pressing power button the computer is powering up and showing me CMOS checksum bad. Is it the CMOS battery problem or something else? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that the CMOS battery's dead, since the CMOS (the BIOS memory) has been restored because of a bad checksum (corrupted data in the CMOS).

Try changing the CMOS battery.

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks!!